# Bad or Badly, which is correct?

Tags: adverbs

Consider this sentence:

> I want to join the contest..

Which is more correct, "so bad" or "so badly"?

I'm leaning towards the latter because it is an adverb and an adverb is required to describe a verb or an adjective. As with the case above, badly should describe want.

I am not sure though if the former is acceptable. And if it is, why so?

Comment: *Bad* is an adverb, too. As a dictionary of your choice will be quick to point out.

Comment: "Badly" sounds more correct to me. "Bad" is popular and American I think.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your use of "so" also.
If you use "so," you would be required to finish the sentence with "that …" and complete the comparison. For example, I want to join the contest so badly that I can't concentrate.

The correct answer would be "***… very* badly**."

Comment: I don't think you are right. Are you implying that I can't say "I am so happy!" without continuing with a that clause?

Comment: Don't you think you're being too prescriptive here? What do you mean by "incorrect" anyway?